# Cannot click on second element in ActionChains function

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning selenium and following a guide online to use ActionChains, however it is outdated so I'm also using the Selenium documentation.

I'm trying to open the below site, click on English to select the language (which works), then click on the cookie one time. It doesn't click on the cookie.

Site: https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker

I have tried re-writing this code many times to get it to click on the cookie but I can't get it to.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys, ActionChains
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "bigCookie")
languages = driver.find_element(By.ID, "langSelect-EN")

ActionChains(driver)\
    .click(languages)\
    .pause(10)\
    .click(cookie)\
    .perform()
```